# How can I set Kivy to auto-animate the position of a shape after an interval?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How can I get Kivy to animate the position of a Rectangle after an interval? Currently, it is only animating the POSITION 1.

However, I want it to wait 3 seconds before it animates to POSITION 2, wait for 3 more seconds, and then animate to POSITION 3

How can I accomplish this? I'm still new to coding.

(No .kv file was used)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyGrid(AnchorLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 12

        for letter in "CANVAS":
            self.inside.add_widget(Label(text=str(letter), color=[1, 1, 1, 1], font_size='80sp', ))

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        with self.canvas:
            # POSITIONS
            self.positionLeft_1 = 50
            self.positionLeft_2 = 150
            self.positionLeft_3 = 250

            Color(1, 1, 1, 1, mode='rgba')
            self.line_Left = Rectangle(pos=(300, 215), size=(1, 100))

            animate_left_line_01 = Animation(pos=(self.positionLeft_1, 215), t='out_circ')
            animate_left_line_02 = Animation(pos=(self.positionLeft_2, 215), t='out_circ')
            animate_left_line_03 = Animation(pos=(self.positionLeft_3, 215), t='out_circ')

            # START ANIMATION
            # MOVE TO POSITION 1
            animate_left_line_01.start(self.line_Left)

            # MOVE TO POSITION 2 AFTER 3 SECONDS
            animate_left_line_02.start(self.line_Left)
            
            # MOVE TO POSITION 3 AFTER 3 SECONDS
            animate_left_line_03.start(self.line_Left)



    def move(self):
        pass

    def update(self, dt):
        self.move()


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.game = MyGrid()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return self.game

    Window.size = (300, 530)
    Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, .5, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that you can do this is by using `Clock.schedule_once()` to schedule each animation:

```
class MyGrid(AnchorLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 12

        for letter in "CANVAS":
            self.inside.add_widget(Label(text=str(letter), color=[1, 1, 1, 1], font_size='80sp', ))

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        # POSITIONS
        self.positionLeft_1 = 50
        self.positionLeft_2 = 150
        self.positionLeft_3 = 250

        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 1, 1, mode='rgba')
            self.line_Left = Rectangle(pos=(300, 215), size=(1, 100))


        # START ANIMATION
        Clock.schedule_once(self.anim1)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.anim2, 3)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.anim3, 6)



    def anim1(self, dt):
        # MOVE TO POSITION 1
        animate_left_line_01 = Animation(pos=(self.positionLeft_1, 215), t='out_circ')
        animate_left_line_01.start(self.line_Left)

    def anim2(self, dt):
        # MOVE TO POSITION 2
        animate_left_line_02 = Animation(pos=(self.positionLeft_2, 215), t='out_circ')
        animate_left_line_02.start(self.line_Left)

    def anim3(self, dt):
        # MOVE TO POSITION 3
        animate_left_line_03 = Animation(pos=(self.positionLeft_3, 215), t='out_circ')
        animate_left_line_03.start(self.line_Left)
```

Comment: John, you are awesome!! That worked like magic. I am very grateful for your help! 

I only started learning to code recently, I still have a lot to learn.